# Unknown locale message on new Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: server, locale

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Server system producing a weird error message about a locale.

Server 20.04:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1
en_US.ISO8859-1: unknown locale
$ echo $LC_ALL
en_US.UTF-8
```

I have one script that is setting the LC_ALL value to this locale. This should be an easy enough fix and just comment out the LC_ALL= line or set it to one of the locales my server is using.

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

But this bugs me... Why is that "unknown locale" message coming up? I have other Ubuntu servers configured (mostly 18.04) that do NOT give this error. Example:

Server 18.04:

```
$ LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1
/usr/share/i18n
$ echo $LC_ALL
en_US.ISO8859-1
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

I've tried some commands suggested but nothing is fixing the problem or showing me what may be the cause. I've tried:

- Ran `locale-gen`
- Ran `dpkg-reconfigure locales`
- Verified contents of `/etc/default/locale`
- Verified contents of `/etc/environment`
- Deleted and rebuilt the `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`

A few articles also mentioned to review or edit the entries in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d` but that directory does not exist on any of my Ubuntu servers.

So my solution is to comment out the LC_ALL line in the problem script. But it does not answer the question. Why do I not get the error on several other servers, just on the new one? Is it possible it is some new behavior in 20.04? I have at least one other 20.04 server that does not get this error,  but I think it was upgraded from 18.04 rather than a full new 20.04 installation.

Any ideas?

TIA. Steve

Edit (1):
One thought (but does not explain why it worked on other Ubuntu servers) is that perhaps the locale name in the problem script was designed for use on a different O/S. I noticed it is using LC_ALL="en_US.ISO8859-1" but that the same locale in Ubuntu is referred to as "en_US ISO8859-1" (has a space before the ISO portion, instead of a period).

Edit (2):
I tried the suggestion from Gunnar and it did not resolve the issue. I sudo'ed to root before trying this.

```
$ locale-gen en_US
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... done
Generation complete.

$ locale -a
C
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.utf8
POSIX

$ LC_ALL="en_US.ISO8859-1"
en_US.ISO8859-1: unknown locale
```

It should be noted that my other Ubuntu servers do not have "en_US.iso88591"  listed as one of the installed/generated locales when I use "locale -a", and yet I do not get the unknown locale error.

I can see the generated latin1 locale is showing as "en_US.iso88591" rather than what I have which is "en_US.ISO8859-1" so I could try changing it to match but that's not the point. The script I have has been on the other Ubuntu 18.04 servers for at least 24 months without getting the error I am seeing on the newly installed 20.04 servers.

Edit(3):
@Gunnar: No luck with any of the three locales

```
$ LC_ALL="en_US.ISO8859-1"
en_US.ISO8859-1: unknown locale
$ LC_ALL="en_US.iso88591"
en_US.iso88591: unknown locale
$ LC_ALL="en_US"
en_US: unknown locale
```

Update:
A reboot did not appear to resolve the "unknown locale" message. We discovered that on the three servers that we have Ubuntu 20.04.4 installed on them, all were giving this message. On the other hand, none of the Ubuntu 18.04.6 servers were producing the error. Despite the fact that we never (to our knowledge) activated the "en_US.ISO8859-1" locale on any of the servers.

As a solution, we simply removed the line from the shell script that was set to "LC_ALL=en_US.ISO8859-1", and thus avoided the message from displaying on the screen.

This still does not explain why the 18.04 servers all seem to accept the name "en_US.ISO8859-1" as a valid LC_ALL value, and yet on the 20.04 servers it reports "unknown locale". But I suspect I am obsessing about a setting that I may never use.

Comment: The Ubuntu name of the latin1 locale is `en_US`. If you generate it, as I suggested in my answer, you can check via `locale -a` if there is an alias which may be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really, for whatever reason, want to use the latin1 locale instead of the UTF-8 one, you need to generate it first.

```
sudo locale-gen en_US
```

Comment: Tried this but it made no difference. See my edit(2)

Comment: @S.Nixon: Well, now you have the alias `en_US.iso88591`. Try either that or `en_US` instead of `en_US.ISO8859-1`.

Comment: @S.Nixon: Possibly `en_US.ISO-8859-1` would work too.

Comment: @S.Nixon: Weird that all those locale names result in errors. Possibly it makes a difference if you reboot.

Comment: I'll try that. No one is using the server yet anyway. Thx.